# flow typing mismatch for function accepting a reducer

Tags: redux, flowtype

I want to create a function which does something to a reducer (it's not important what it is, just some transformation, similar to combineReducers). i have problem when i want to abstract the `state` for the reducer.
Here is the simplified reducer used for some component:

```
type someState = {
  foo: number,
};
export const someSimpleReducer = (state: someState) => state;

type StateAbstract = {}; // this doesn't work
// type StateAbstract = any; // this works
```

and here the abstract transform function with abstracted state:

```
declare type SimpleReducer<S> = (state: S) => S;

export const transformReducer = (reducer: SimpleReducer<StateAbstract>) => ({
  reducer,
});

transformReducer(someSimpleReducer);
```

i see the following flow error:

> Flow: Cannot call `transformReducer` with `someSimpleReducer` bound to `reducer` because property `foo` is missing in `StateAbstract` [1] but exists in `someState` [2] in the first argument

If i use `type StateAbstract = any` then i don't see any error...
How can i write `StateAbstract` type so it's not `any`, but is an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare type SimpleReducer<S> = (state: S) => S;
```

declares a type `SimpleReducer` which is a function that takes an S and returns an S.

`transformReducer` is a function that takes a `SimpleReducer<StateAbstract>` i.e. a function that takes a `StateAbstract` and returns a `StateAbstract`.

`transformReducer` shouldn't care about what type that reducer function takes and returns. Instead of using a concrete type use a generic:

```
export const transformReducer = <S>(reducer: SimpleReducer<S>) => ({reducer})
```

[Here it is on Try Flow.](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgDOcAtngMoYCGGBAvGAN6phhRxwBcYAdgK4kARngBOAGlQBfANyoAxnB6EMRUhQCWJHDDwAlPABM+c0WAYAKZTTzdiZStYCUZgHxFqtWagN45MKiIE2Phg5JraeobGogA85G4WVrTc5M50buReeAAeOHAiKgpKKhgiVErsIiT6RiYiZmBxLuaBtaIp4To10SJNaW7mzKytPRKSjl6l5YSV1VF1lmphWl3zohMsrFtgQA)

Comment: Thanks! but what if i want to make sure `transformReducer` doesn't accept any wrong functions? Reducer should accept `state` as an `object`, not `string`. So i want to throw error on this situation?

`const improperReducer = (state: string) => state;`
`transformReducer(improperReducer);`

or maybe i am just overdiligent?

Comment: [updated Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgDOcAtngMoYCGGBAvGAN6phhRxwBcYAdgK4kARngBOAGlQBfANyoAxnB6EMRUhQCWJHDDwAlPABM+c0WAYAKZTTzdiZStYCUZgHxFqtWagN45MKiIE2Phg5JraeobGogA85G4WVrTc5M50buReeAAeOHAiKgpKKhgiVErsIiT6RiYiZmBxLuaBtaIp4To10SJNaW7mzKytPRKSjl6l5YSV1VF1lmphWl3zohMsrFus8orKYOEicPgi3XUNlh427iLqPADm-e7WslMV+XNtIuaHx6Jn61kQA)

Comment: If you want to only allow reducers that take objects, then `SimpleReducer` should be declared like `SimpleReducer = (state: Object) => Object`. And transformReducer is simply `transformReducer = (reducer: SimpleReducer) => ({reducer})`. [Try Flow Example](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgDOcAtngMoYCGGBAvGAN6phhRxwBcYAdgK4kARngBOAGlQBfANyoAxnB6EMRUhQCWJHDDwAlPABM+c0WAYAKZTTzdiZStYCUZgHxFqtWagN45MKiIE2Phg5JraeobGphZWtNwA8oIAVr4YznRuSalyGF54AB44cCIqCkoqGCJUSuwiJPpGJiJmYOaBTaLcYVo6jdEiGW7mzKwdAxKSjl5VNYR1DVHNlmo9Ef3N0yysO6zyispg4SJw+CIbMW1xNu4i6jwA5kPu1rKztSWLnSLmx6eiF0GsiAA)

Comment: Oh and in case you want to keep SimpleReducer generic then you can specify the concrete type in transformReducer like so: `transformReducer = (reducer: SimpleReducer<Object>) => ({ reducer })`

Comment: Yes, that last note is i think the proper answer to my question (replacing `{}` with `Object`). But your other ideas allowed me to look at the problem from different perspective.